# Cut and show json value in view using Angular

Tags: json, angular, view

Hi I have a GET response data which is like `"DeletionDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"`. So what I need to do is I don't need time `T00:00:00` from the information. Is there any method to cut the value and show only half the value in views ?  `"DeletionDate": "0001-01-01"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
 {{ today | date : "yyyy-MM-dd" }} // put DeletionDate in place of today
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First Method -

   ```
   {{"0001-01-01T00:00:00" | date : "yyyy-MM-dd"}}
   ```
2. Second Method

   ```
    {{getDate("0001-01-01T00:00:00")}}

    getDate(date){
      return date.split("T")[0];
    }
   ```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umzg2d?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

In your TS file:

```
DeletionDate = "0001-01-01T00:00:00";
```

In your HTML file:

```
{{ DeletionDate | date : "yyyy-MM-dd" }}
```

If your are new to Angular please refer the ***[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8fetny?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)***